# How to deal with unobserved heterogeneity in binary logistic regression ? (using SPSS)

Tags: regression, logistic, spss, binary-data, overdispersion

I have performed a binary logistic regression with SPSS.

I am trying to deal with the phenomenon of unobserved heterogeneity but actually I have not fully understood how to test it and how to deal with it using SPSS.

I would be grateful if someone can help me with the issue.

I have already red some papers on the topic, but they did not help much.

Mood, Carina. 2010. “Logistic Regression: Why We Cannot Do What We Think We Can Do, and What We Can Do about It.” European Sociological Review 26 (1): 67–82. doi:10.1093/esr/jcp006.

As far as I can understand (I am a researcher in management) there is no way to deal with unobserved heterogeneity (or overdispersion) in binomial logistic regression.

Thus, practically what I should do in order to ensure the goodness of my binary logistic regression? (I am working with SPSS).

Can you advise me papers explaining that unobserved heterogeneity is not manageable with binary logistic regression?

I find this paper that seems to validate my hypothesis

Skrondal, A., & Rabe-Hesketh, S. (2007). Redundant overdispersion parameters in multilevel models for categorical responses. Journal of Educational and Behavioral Statistics, 32(4), 419–430. https://doi.org/10.3102/1076998607302629